# Two implementations for an interface with different types - Is this not possible?

Tags: java, generics, methods, types, interface

I have an interface like this:

```
 interface Transformer { 
     public String transform( List<Object> elements );
 }
```

implementations:

```
 class XMLTransformer implements Transformer{ 
     public String transform( List<MyXMLElements> elements );
 }

 class TXTTransformer implements Transformer { 
     public String transform( List<MyTXTElements> elements );
 }
```

But note that MyXMLElements and MyTXTElements do NOT have a common parent. Those are completely different objects.

Tried this as well in the interface:

```
    public String transform( List<? extends Object> elements );
    public String transform( List<?> elements );
    public String transform( List<T extends Object> elements );
    public String transform( List<T> elements );
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic interface:

```
interface Transformer<T> { 
    public String transform( List<T> elements );
}
```

And make your class implement different instantiations of that generic type:

```
class XMLTransformer implements Transformer<MyXMLElements> { 
    public String transform( List<MyXMLElements> elements ) {
    }
}

class TXTTransformer implements Transformer<MyTXTElements> { 
     public String transform( List<MyTXTElements> elements ) {
     }
}
```

Here, `Transformer<MyXMLElements>` is an instantiation of the generic type `Transformer<T>`. Simlarly `Transformer<MyTXTElements>` is another instantiation of the same generic type.

Comment: When I call a method with a either XML or TXT type, it automatically identifies which class/method to use?

Comment: @KevinRave. Yup. Exactly. For `Transformer<MyXMLElements>` reference with an `XMLTransformer` instance, it will call method in `XMLTransformer`. Try implementing it.

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible with generics - declare a generic type parameter for your interface:

```
interface Transformer<T> { 
    public String transform( List<T> elements );
}
```

Then your implementing classes simply have to use the actual class name in place of the generic type parameter on the interface:

```
class XMLTransformer implements Transformer<MyXmlElements>{ 
   public String transform( List<MyXMLElements> elements ) {}
}

class TXTTransformer implements Transformer<MyTXTElements> { 
   public String transform( List<MyTXTElements> elements ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the [generics type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). For JVM you are implemting the interfaces with List of elements in both the cases, which is totally acceptable.